# spring security, when i have a success access in login its redirect me to the same login page

Tags: java, spring-security

it my first project with spring security 6 and i use a custom filterchain, when i login in my thymeleaf form send the user and the password to my controller "login1" dont get inside and i redirect the same login page with code 302, but when in my Config security change .loginProcessingUrl("/login1") to .loginProcessingUrl("/login1!"), my program works, but i dont know why if ("login1!") doesnt exist in my controller class , can somebody  help me ?

when i try login sometime redirect to a blank page or the same login page

```
here is mi login1.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title>Spring Security Example </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div th:if="${param.error}">
            Invalid username and password.
        </div>
        <div th:if="${param.logout}">
            You have been logged out
        </div>
        <form th:action="@{/login1}" method="post">
           
            <div><label> User Email : <input type="text" name="username"/> </label></div>
            <div><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </label></div>
            <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
here is my controller
package com.prueba.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView;

import com.prueba.dao.Userdao;
import com.prueba.model.UserEntity;

@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    Userdao dao;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "home";
    }

    @GetMapping("/login1") // llamamos a login
    public String login() {
        return "login1";
    }


    @PostMapping(value = "/login1") // metemos parametros en login y luego devolvemos hello
    private String acceso1(@RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("password") String password) {
        //System.out.println("entre");
        
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
        //System.out.println(auth.getPrincipal().toString());
        
        boolean a = authenticationManager.authenticate(auth).isAuthenticated();
        //System.out.println("es authenticado " + a);
        
        authenticationManager.authenticate(auth);
        //System.out.println("estoyaqui");
        return "hello";

    }

    @GetMapping("/lista")
    public void lista() {
        for (UserEntity t : dao.findAll()) {
            System.out.println(t.toString());
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

```
here is my ConfigSecurity
package com.prueba.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;

import com.prueba.service.LoginSuccesHandlerImp;

@Configuration//decimos que vamos a confirgurar metodos propios de spring
public class ConfigSecurity {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    LoginSuccesHandlerImp loginSuccesHandlerImp;
    
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        
        
        
        

        return http
                .csrf(config -> config.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorizeHttpRequests) ->
                authorizeHttpRequests
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                        
                        
                        )
                        .formLogin((form) -> form
                                .loginPage("/login1")
                                .permitAll()
                                .loginProcessingUrl("/login1")
                                //.successHandler(loginSuccesHandlerImp)
                            
                                
                                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                                
                                
                            )
                            .logout((logout) -> logout.permitAll())
                            
                            
                
                .sessionManagement(session -> {
                    session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
                })
               
                
                .build();
        
    
        
        
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder password() {
        
        return  NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager autheticationManager(HttpSecurity http,PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) throws Exception {
        //enviamos un objeto del tipo AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class
        //le enviamos el usuario que vamos autenticar que esta arriba userDetailsService ()
        System.out.println("entro aqui 3");
        
        return http.
                getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
                .and()
                .build();
        
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler appAuthenticationSuccessHandler(){
         return new LoginSuccesHandlerImp();
    }
}
```

```
here is my UserDetailsServiceImp
package com.prueba.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.prueba.dao.Userdao;
import com.prueba.model.UserEntity;

@Service

public class UserDetailsServiceImp implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    Userdao dao;
    
    
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserEntity user1 = dao.findByName(username).orElseThrow(()->new UsernameNotFoundException("usuario no encontrado"));
        System.out.println("user1"+ user1.toString());
        
        
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user1.getRol()));
        var user2 = new User(user1.getUsername()
                ,user1.getPassword()
                ,true
                ,true
                ,true
                ,true
                ,authorities);
        System.out.println(user2.toString());
        return user2;
    }
```

```
its my pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.prueba.inicio</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProyectoEjed</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Pruebaaax</name>
    <description>Shop with security and JWT</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Are you getting some more details in log stack trace?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).